# MongoDB query an array of documents for specific match

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to search the `transactions` array looking for a specific match. In this example, by `pipedrive_id`.

[image]

This is what I tried (as per [mongodb instructions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents) and this other [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307132/mongodb-query-array-of-documents))

```
const pipedrive_id = 1677;
const inner_pipedrive_id = 1838;

const result = await Transactions.find({
    pipedrive_id,
    'transactions': { $elemMatch: { 'pipedrive_id': inner_pipedrive_id } }
});

const result2= await Transactions.find({
    'transactions': { $elemMatch: { 'pipedrive_id': inner_pipedrive_id } }
});

const result3 = await Transactions.find({
    'transactions.pipedrive_id': inner_pipedrive_id
});
```

And each result itteration returns all `transaction` items (all 6 items, instead of 2 [that's how many Mark Smith has in the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate to filter out the array. Something like this

You can remove `$project` if you want all the fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      pipedrive_id: "1677"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$transactions"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "transactions.pipedrive_id": "1838"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      pipedrive_id: 1,
      transactions: 1
    }
  }
])
```

You can check the [Mongo playground here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qeMGaLpyHBZ)

Answer (score 1):

As the [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), `$elemMatch` matches documents that contain an array field with **at least one element that matches** the criteria.
To filter the result inside the array, you will need to use `$filter` from aggregation
Ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/